# new RAM for various HP notebook models?

Tags: memory, hp-pavilion

HP Pavilion dv7-4141eb Entertainment Notebook PC

Searching on kingston, the serial number isn't mentioned. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

It just jumps right over. Crucial isn't loading the DV7 series numbers for some reason, so can't select anything there.

I suppose the question is: is any of the other numbers compatible with mine? I really don't want to buy a stick of RAM that won't work for my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most memory of the following specification will work in that model

DDR3 - 1066 MHz / PC3-8500 - unbuffered - non-ECC

You can call Crucial on the phone to have them look up models not listed on the website, or use the system scanner tab.